# How do I go from one route to another using React-Router?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have the below code. It exists in a file that has the route "login". From root, I have another route, "create-account".
Whenever I click on this "a" element in Login.jsx to bring me to "create-account", it takes me to "login/create-account" instead. I've also tried "./create-account" and "../create-account".
Is there anything I can do? I can't find any solutions.
I am using React-Router-Dom 6.9.0.

Login.jsx

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function LoginForm() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div className="loginForm">

      <h1>Login</h1>
      <p>
        Don't have an account? 
        <a onClick={() => navigate("../create-account")}> Create an account </a>.
      </p>
```

And my App.jsx (which is serving as my Router)

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie'

import Master from './Master.jsx'
import HomePage from './HomePage.jsx'
import DashCards from './DashCards.jsx'
// Authentication Pages
import LoginForm from './Auth/SignInForm.jsx'
//import CreateAccountForm from './Auth/CreateAccount.jsx'
//import LogoutPage from './Auth/SignOut.jsx'

export const AppContext = createContext()

export default function App() {

  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['token'])
  let [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(cookies.token !== undefined)
  let [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState([])
  let [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ authenticated, setAuthenticated, loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser, setCookie, removeCookie, users, setUsers, }}>
      <Router className="react-stuff">
        <Routes>

          <Route path="/" element={<Master/>} >
            <Route index element={<HomePage />} />

            <Route path="login" element={<LoginForm />} />
            {/* <Route path="logout" element={<LogoutPage />} /> */}
            <Route path="create-account" element={<div>404: Page Under Construction</div>} />
          </Route>

        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </AppContext.Provider >
  )
}
```

Comment: Try absolute path `navigate("/create-account")`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using raw anchor tags then you'll want to prevent the default action.

```
<a
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("../create-account");
  }}
>
  Create an account
</a>
```

It would be better to just render a `Link` component though which will already correctly handle this behavior. You'll need only provide the target path you want to navigate to.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Link to="../create-account">
  Create an account
</Link>
```

Depending where this `LoginForm` is being rendered, using the relative path `"../create-account"` may not be correct. If all you need to do is navigate to `"/create-account"` then just use the absolute path instead.

```
<Link to="/create-account">
  Create an account
</Link>
```